# How can I append a table row with jquery without affecting the tables I have inside that table?

Tags: jquery

For example if I have a table with an inner table:

```
<table id="table_1">
  <tr>
    <td><table id="table_2">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And I have apply this jquery code:

```
$.get("../php/new_row.php", {id: id}).done(function(data) {
  $('#table_1 tr:last').after(data);
});
```

It applies the new row to the table_2 and not the table_1...please help me, I dont understand why this happens if I'm specifying table_1...Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you console log the return value of `$('#table_1 tr:last')`, you'll see that it is matching both `<tr>` elements, because they both match the selector.

I think you want to add the `>` selector to your chain, something like

```
$.get("../php/new_row.php", {id: id}).done(function(data) {
  $('#table_1 > tr:last').after(data);
});
```

to only get IMMEDIATE children of `#table_1`

You can read about that selector [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#child-selectors)

EDIT

An alternative solution could just be

```
$('#table_1').append(data)
```

This will add whatever `data` is (hopefully HTML) as the last element inside the selected table (So after the last `<tr>`). If that doesn't work, we'll need more information to help you.

Comment: Hi!! Thank you for answeing but its not working, it worked before but like I said it added the new row to table_2 but I added the '>' and it doesnt do anything, it doesnt even bring an error

Answer (score 0):

Use the direct descendent selector:

```
$('#table_1 > tr:last').after(data);
```

Comment: Hi!! Thank you for answeing but its not working, it worked before but like I said it added the new row to table_2 but I added the '>' and it doesnt do anything, it doesnt even bring an error